# Tick a “Pass Through” check box on the “Available Inputs Column” on a Fuzzy Lookup Transformation using BIML

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, bids, biml

I am using SQL Server 2008 BIDs / BIML, how do I tick the check box on the “Available Inputs Column” on the Columns tab of the Fuzzy Lookup Transformation Editor, column name is inputFile_id?

I do not won’t to match on this column just pass it through the FLT; simply tick the inputFile_id “Pass Through” checkbox on the columns tab of the Fuzzy Lookup Transformation Editor. Hopefully below a screenshot of the checkbox.

```
        <Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
        <Connections>
            <OleDbConnection Name="SourceData" ConnectionString="Provider=SQLNCLI10;Server=myServer;Initial Catalog=myCat;Integrated Security=SSPI;" DelayValidation="true" />
        </Connections>
        <Packages>
            <Package Name="_step01_CreateIndex" ConstraintMode="Linear">
                <Tasks>
                    <Dataflow Name="My Dataflow Task">
                        <Transformations>
                            <OleDbSource Name="list of people to match to reference list" ConnectionName="SourceData">
                                <DirectInput>select TOP 1000 inputFile_id, forename, surname from dbo.peopleToMatchInputFile</DirectInput>
                            </OleDbSource>
                            <!-- Column names must be the same in dbo.peopleToMatchInputFile AND dbo.referenceListOfPeople. -->
                            <!-- A column from dbo.peopleToMatchInputFile MUST BE mapped to a column in dbo.referenceListOfPeople. -->
                            <FuzzyLookup Name="FLT - Generate new index" 
                                         MatchIndexOptions="GenerateAndPersistNewIndex"  
                                         MatchIndexName="dbo.referenceListOfPeopleINDEX"
                                         ConnectionName="SourceData"  
                                         Exhaustive="false" >
                                <ExternalReferenceTableInput Table="dbo.referenceListOfPeople" />
                                <Inputs>
                                    <Column SourceColumn="forename" TargetColumn="forename" MatchTypeExact ="false" MinSimilarity ="95" />
                                    <Column SourceColumn="surname" TargetColumn="surname" MatchTypeExact="true" />
                                    <Column SourceColumn="inputFile_id" TargetColumn="inputFile_id" PassThrough="true" IsUsed="false"/>
                                </Inputs>
                                <Outputs>
                                    <Column SourceColumn="lookup_id" TargetColumn="lookup_id" />
                                    <Column SourceColumn="forename" TargetColumn="OutputAlias_forename" />
                                    <Column SourceColumn="surname" TargetColumn="surname" IsUsed="false" />
                                    <Column SourceColumn="streetName" TargetColumn="streetName" />
                                    <Column SourceColumn="dependantLocality" TargetColumn="dependantLocality" />
                                    <Column SourceColumn="postalCounty" TargetColumn="postalCounty" />
                                    <Column SourceColumn="postTown" TargetColumn="OutputAlias_postTown" />
                                </Outputs>
                            </FuzzyLookup>
                        </Transformations>
                    </Dataflow>
                </Tasks>
            </Package>
        </Packages>
    </Biml>


    <#@ template language="C#" hostspecific="true"#>
    <#@ import namespace="System.Data" #>
    <#@ import namespace="Varigence.Hadron.CoreLowerer.SchemaManagement" #>

        <!--
        CREATE TABLE [dbo].[peopleToMatchInputFile](
        [inputFile_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [forename] [varchar](35) NOT NULL,
        [surname] [varchar](35) NOT NULL,
        [streetName] [varchar](80) NULL,
        [batchNo] [int] NULL
        )


    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[referenceListOfPeople](
        [lookup_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [forename] [varchar](35) NOT NULL,
        [surname] [varchar](35) NOT NULL,
        [streetName] [varchar](80) NULL,
        [dependantLocality] [varchar](35) NULL,
        [postTown] [varchar](35) NULL,
        [postalCounty] [varchar](35) NULL
        )
        -->
```

[image: checkbox]

Comment: i think i'm getting closer to an answer, i may have to use a transformer http://bimlscript.com/Walkthrough/Details/68

Comment: i've rephrased the question to be a bit more clear. I have found how to answer this question without changing the BIML script but modifying the SQL, not ideal but works, was hoping to resolve it using BIML

Comment: Varigence Support say that there have been some recent fixes to the BimlEngine.dll and better support for the Passthrough in fuzzy lookup. I am awaiting them to send the dll to confirm this